# How to convert arelational data base into an ontology (owl)

Tags: database, owl, ontology

I want to convert a relational data base into an ontology. Which the best tool for doing that?

Comment: Since Protégé plugins are [suitable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43788954/7879193) tools for you, I recommend you [Ontop](https://github.com/ontop/ontop/wiki/Easy-Tutorial:-Using-Ontop-from-Protege). In my opinion, Ontop is the best tool to start with. It supports both DM and R2RML (as well as its own mapping format). Ontop is also available as standalone command line software.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [R2RML](https://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/). The direct mappings are a pretty easy way to quickly convert relational data into RDF.

Comment: To my mind, RDB2RDF DM is rather opposite to R2RML, than is a part of R2RML. Although, of course, an R2RML processor [MAY](https://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/#default-mappings) include an R2RML default mapping generator.