# Convert an OWL ontology into a relational database

Tags: database, relational-database, owl, ontology

Is there any tool to quickly get a relational database from an owl ontology?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert arelational data base into an ontology (owl)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740648/how-to-convert-arelational-data-base-into-an-ontology-owl)

Comment: @Catty42, look into [this article](http://www.isca.in/rjrs/archive/v4/i4/12.ISCA-RJRS-2013-488.pdf)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Michael  It's not duplicated i just want to convert a RDB to ontology in one hand, and in the other hand i want to convert an ontology into RDB.

Answer (score 1):

[OWL2ToRDB](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/OWL2ToRDB) is a Protégé plugin that can convert an owl ontology into RDB.